# Econometric models?

Tags: time-series, arima, econometrics, seasonality, model-comparison

I'm confused about econometrics models. Let's  say I used a daily stock market index  for 5 years, and I want to see how oil price affect the stock markets return , let's assume ( as a fact ) that oil price affect ALL the period negatively, and I use

- VAR
- ARIMA
- ARDL, and
- GARCH

  for the same data.

What will each model tell me?

Will all of them reach a similar conclusion like oil price affect stock market return negatively?

How would the interpretation be different between each model?

Answer (score 2):

You represent the data with a model to fulfill a certain task, e.g. to describe the data or to forecast or predict values which are not in the dataset. For some tasks some models are more appropriate than other. Therefore you should think of the problem you have and then you should look for a model/way/method to solve this problem. Generally if all of you models tell you the same, e.g. the oil price affects the stock market negatively, than you can be relatively sure that this is really the case.

If the models tell you different inferences you should think about the models:

- Does on models detect for autocorrelation?
- What about unit roots, structural changes and stationarity?
- Are there unobserved effects or is there endogeneity?
- etc.

---

Your models are always only a representation of your data. Some models are more appropriate for some data and some models are more appropriate for other data.

---

- VAR

is a model for multiple time-series. If you only have a univariate time series VAR is not appropriate.

- ARIMA

ARIMA and its variante seasonal ARIMA usually perform suboptimal when you data has multiple seasonalities or complex seasonality patterns, e.g. daily seasonalities with 365 periods a year.

- ARDL

Might be a reasonable choice. You can use it even when your data is non-stationary.

- GARCH

Might also be a reasonable choice- especially when there is volatility clustering.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that "econometric models" is anyhow a closed, or clearly defined set of models. Econometrics is basically a statistics applied to economy (plus some confusing mathematical notation), and there's lots of models used for such problems.

The answer is: yes and no. *Yes*, because given you have sufficient data and used your models correctly, then they all should be able to approximate the modeled  "truth". *No*, because the reason for having different models for modelling similar problems, is that they all focus on slightly different things, optimize different stuff, so *won't* give you exactly the same answers. Moreover, in many cases you simply can use all those models for same problem, e.g. VAR is multivariate, while ARIMA univariate. However if different models gave you *very* different answers, then I'd start wondering if there aren't any problems with the data.